# MySQL indexing with where clause

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a little question:

If i have three queries like:

```
1. SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1=3 AND col2=4 WHERE col3 > 15 ORDER BY col3 ASC

2. SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1=3 AND col2=4 ORDER BY col3 ASC

3. SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1=3 AND col2=4 AND MATCH ( col6 ) AGAINST ( "text" ) ORDER BY col3 ASC
```

What would be the correct order for indexing the table?

My guess:

```
1. col1, col2, col3
2. col1, col2, col3
3. col1, col2, col6, col3
```

Am i wrong ?

LE:

After i add index, for 1:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON table ( col1, col2, col3 )
```

The query is:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table IGNORE INDEX ( idx ) WHERE col1 = 5 AND col2 = 5 AND col3 > 56000 ORDER BY col3 ASC

rows: 100306

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table USE INDEX ( idx ) WHERE col1 = 5 AND col2 = 5 AND col3 > 56000 ORDER BY col3 ASC

rows: 100306
```

all the rows are generated with:

```
$arr = array( );

for( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++ )
    $arr[ intval( $i ) ] = intval( $i );

shuffle( $arr );


for( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++ )
{
    $jud = $i % 10;
    $or = 10 - ( $i % 10 );

    $db_request = $db->prepare( "INSERT INTO table ( col1, col2, col3 ) VALUES ( '$jud', '$or', '".$arr[ $i ]."' )" );

    $db_request->execute( array( ) );
}
```

at possible_keys is showing the index, but at Extra, it is not sayin "Using index"

So, what is wrong?

Comment: [_Index Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) recommends `(col1, col2, col3)` or `(col2, col1, col3)` for #1 and #2.

Answer (score 1):

`MATCH()` is for fulltext indexes. It can't use the plain type of index. You'd need to create a separate index of the fulltext type:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (col6);
```

Other than that, your index on col1, col2, col3 is correct.

You might like my presentation, [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

---

The query uses the index if you see it in the `key` column of the EXPLAIN report.

"Using index" really means "Using *only* the index." In other words, it was able to do the searching and sorting using the index, *and* the index contained all the columns needed by the select-list, so it didn't need to look up the row in the table at all. When this happens, it's called an index-only query, and the index is sometimes called a "covering index."

If you use `SELECT *` it's not usually possible to get "Using index" unless your index contains all the columns of that table.

You will also not see "Using index" if the query skips the index and does a table-scan, or if the index used is the PRIMARY KEY index.

Answer (score 0):

the index order given will work the most efficiently.

```
1. col1, col2, col3
2. col1, col2, col3
3. col1, col2, col6, col3
```